# Excel VBA code runs by itself when stepping through

Tags: vba, excel, step-through

Sorry if this is a duplicate, however I doubt that, as I've been Googling for an hour and no search hits even come close to what i'm looking for.

My macro is run from Excel, it opens a PowerPoint presentation from a Sharepoint and handles Excels that are embedded in the pptx.

My problem is that whenever I am `stepping through` the code, all lines are executed one-by-one as they should, but when I run the line `.Range("A" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Follow` (this opens the pptx), the code just runs all the way to the end automatically. Keep in mind, I am **stepping through** - and I am not accidentally hitting F5, or anything like that.

I'm suspecting it's either the hyperlink, or the fact that I am handling PowerPoint from Excel, but can't find the reason.

I am experiencing an issue and want to find where the code goes wrong, but can't as it just "runs away" after following the hyperlink.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `Stop` after the `.Follow` line?

Comment: Does the presentation open successfully?

Comment: I have had the same issue when debugging hyperlinks. The simplest solution is to just add a breakpoint immediately following the code running the hyperlink. You can also use 'Debug.Assert' with a condition for it to evaluate. For example 'Debug.Assert 1=2' would cause the code to break at this line. I dont personally find this useful, but I am sure there are those out there that would rather only step through when there is a problem :).